# 'Connection Refused' EXCEPT filezilla

Tags: remote-access

I have a rather strange problem, I am unable to connect to a host using any other ftp client or putty EXCEPT filezilla.

This was not the case two weeks back. The error I am now getting is "Connection Refused". The issue is reproduced on several machines.

Is filezilla using some other protocol?

Comment: I would recommend troubleshooting the thing that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Well I found the issue, it seems that the hosting has disabled SSH access. Filezilla uses FTP protocol so it was working. WinSCP was set to use SSH instead of FTP so that wasn't working as well.